# How can I change the name of the template that is passed to the @Render decorator in the Interceptor?

Tags: javascript, nestjs, nestjs-i18n

How can I change the name of the template that is passed to the @Render decorator in the Interceptor? I need to add the desired locale to the template url, depending on the user's language. I'm trying to do this, but it doesn't work. How can I do this?

```js
@Injectable()
export class RenderByLanguageInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
  constructor(private reflector: Reflector) {}

  intercept(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler): Observable<any> {
    const template = this.reflector.getAllAndOverride<string>(RENDER_METADATA, [
          context.getHandler(),
          context.getClass(),
    ]);

    const lang = context.switchToHttp().getRequest().i18nLang;
    SetMetadata(RENDER_METADATA, `${lang}/${template}`);

    return next.handle();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`SetMetadata` is a decorator from Nest's library as a helper function. What you're needing to do is use the `Reflect` API and do something along the lines of

```js
Reflect.defineMetadata(
  RENDER_METADATA,
  `${lang}/${tempalte}`,
  context.getClass(),
  context.getHandler()
);
```

Where `Reflect` is from [`reflect-metadata`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/reflect-metadata). This should set the metadata appropriately, so it can be read later. With this approach, you will have to make sure the metadata is set every time, as there's no falling back to the original metadata in the `@Render()` decorator.

Comment: The problem is that I can't get context. switch To Http ().GetRequest().i18nlang, it looks like it's not in the context yet, how do I get it after i18nLang appears in the context?

Comment: When does `i18nlang` appear on the req object? How does that get populated?

Comment: To the AppModule to imports

Comment: The AppModule's imports dont affect the request object per request. The AppModule is just there for defining  the the modules, providers, and controllers used in the application

Comment: return next.handle().pipe(
      map((data) => {
        const lang = context.switchToHttp().getRequest().i18nLang;
        console.log(lang);
        return data;
      }),
    ); - This is how I can get lang. How else can I solve my problem, with changing the template path depending on the user's language?

Comment: Just do the `Reflect.defineMetadata` in another `tap` after that `map`? I don't know what the new problem is. The above metadata re-definition should be what you're looking for